# C# Excel Format Conditions - Invalid Parameter Exception

Tags: c#, excel, formatting, interop, conditional-statements

I'm trying to color even/odd rows at excel.
Here is my code:

```
FormatCondition format = (FormatCondition)(range.FormatConditions.Add(XlFormatConditionType.xlExpression,
                            XlFormatConditionOperator.xlEqual, "=MOD(ROW(),2) = 0"));
Interior interior = format.Interior;
interior.Color = ColorTranslator.ToOle(Color.Red);
```

When i try to debug, got an error which says "Invalid Parameter. HRESULT returns 0x80070057(E_INVALIDARG)" (sorry, can't post image i dont have that much reputation)

Yes i tried clearing ASP.NET Temprory files from Framework but it did not worked for me.
And i tried like this:

```
FormatCondition format = (FormatCondition)(range.FormatConditions.Add(XlFormatConditionType.xlExpression,
                        XlFormatConditionOperator.xlEqual, "=MOD(ROW(),2) = 0", Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing));
```

I tried everthing i find but the result didn't changed VS gives me "Invalid Parameter" error everytime.

What should i do?

Answer (score 0):

I think you must use a ; instead of a , in the Mod() function. Just had the same problem with the code from the original poster.